# Part title framed

Tags: titlesec, framed, parts

I was wondering how I could put a blue (`{cmyk}{1,0.80,0.30,0.05}`) coloured frame around my chapter titles, leaving out "PART 1" and just give the part title name itself, as is depicted in the picture below, also making the letters distance in the title bigger than usual (8 pt).

It should also be placed in the exact centre of the page.
I'm using the `titlesec` package.

Frame should have a width of 2.25 pt.

Thanks!

[image: Part title box]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1,0.80,0.30,0.05}

\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\sopart{}{8pt}{20pt}{16em}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{2.25pt}\color{myblue}}
{}
{5mm}
{\Large\sffamily\filcenter\color{myblue}\MakeUppercase{\sopart{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\part{Part name}
\end{document}
```

Here I've defined a new command `\sopart` for letterspacing, but this requires loading `titlesec` with the `explicit` option.

The following, instead, is a solution that uses the `letterspace` package (`microtype` bundle) for letterspacing and doesn't require the `explicit` option for `titlesec`, but it doesn't work with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1,0.80,0.30,0.05}

\usepackage[letterspace=600]{letterspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{2.25pt}\color{myblue}}
{}
{5mm}
{\Large\sffamily\filcenter\color{myblue}\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\part{Part name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So now I'm using your code, but now I can't force the exclusion of the part title in the table of contents with `\part*{Part name}`, and replacing it by a chapter title in ToC by `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Part name}` Solution?

Comment: @mmhenrot Redefining `\part` formatting is problematic. If you are using just starred `\part`s this can be solved by adding `\makeatletter\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{}\makeatother` in your preamble.

Comment: @mmhenrot Otherwise, if you are using `report` or `book` classes, it suffices to add `\titleclass{\part}{top}` just after loading `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems close to what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\fboxrule=3pt
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
  {\normalfont\color[cmyk]{1,0.80,0.30,0.05}}
  {\filright}{12pt}
  {\Huge\scshape\filcenter\color{black}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Part Name Here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `titlesec`  and the `framed` package. I used the `LetterSpace` font feature with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, x11names]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[explicit, newparttoc, newlinetospace]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{ugentblauw}{cmyk}{1 0.8 0.3 0.05}%
\colorlet{shadecolor}{ugentblauw}

\titleformat{\part}[block]{\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge\fontspec[LetterSpace=20.0]{NimbusSanL-Regu}\filcenter\color{ugentblauw}}%
{}{0pt}{\setlength\FrameRule{2.25pt}\begin{framed}\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}#1\end{framed}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\color{white} \begin {shaded*}\bfseries}{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge#1\end{shaded*}}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{ugentblauw}}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents 

\part{PART NAME\\ HERE}

\chapter{Chapter} 

This is some text.

\section{Section}
Indeed, text it is.
\bibliography{bibinflu}

\end{document}
```

[image]